# GSP/trig anomaly

Tags: trigonometry

Using Geometer's Sketch Pad, I plotted the polar equation of the ellipse with centre as origin and a large value of 'a' relative to 'b' on a Cartesian grid and was surprised to see superimposed on the curve of period pi I was expecting a shallow curve of period 4 pi. No trig function can have a period greater than 2 pi. What's going on?

Comment: Doesn't $\sin(x/2)$ have a period of $4\pi$?

Comment: Trig functions can have a period greater than $2\pi$. I think you are thinking of the parent trigonometric functions, $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be any positive real number.  Then the function $y=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{P}\right)$ has period $P$.